# REST API. Hide "password" field on response

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, rest, bson

I am very beginner at C# .Net Core. I use MongoDB to store some object. For explaining my problem, suppose, that I have two methods in "UserController": register and get.
When I use regeister method, I send user object (something like that):

```
{
    id: 1,
    email: "test@test.com",
    name: "GoodUserName",
    password: "12345"
}
```

**but when I use get-method, I want to hide password field, and I expect to get something like that (without password):**

```
{
    id: 1,
    email: "test@test.com",
    name: "GoodUserName"
}
```

I try to use BsonIgnore,

```
Class User 
{
    ...
    [BsonIgnore]
    string password {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

but when I use register method there is empty password field.
My problem is when I use my "get" controller, the "User" object in response include password field. Please, tell me best practise way to hide password on response.

Comment: Usually, you'd have "Data Transfer Objects (DTO)" and map those to and from DataBase-Objects (sometimes called "Entities"). That way, you can control what information you want to hide (or add).

Comment: BTW: I guess (and hope) this is no production code. You really should _never_ save plain text passwords to your db (but that's enough content for a series of lectures).

Comment: You can easily blank  the password field in code before returning the object to your client

Comment: ^^ For the mapping, there are even libraries to make that easier (as in "spare you from writing boilerplate code"): like Mapster, AutoMapper ...

Comment: Why not use .net identity? this handles a lot for you and is still customizable.
For core you can look it here what it is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the simple solution to your problem is to exclude the password property by using an exclusion projection when retrieving the user like this:

```cs
var projection = Builders<User>.Projection.Exclude(u => u.password);

var user = (await userCollection.FindAsync(
    filter: u => u.id == 1,
    options: new FindOptions<User, User> { Projection = projection })
    ).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

but... ideally you'd never wanna expose your data models/entities to your frontend like this. you should be using separate view models or DTOs and map between your domain entities on the way in as well as out. look up CQRS pattern for a good implementation.